# How can I find all the SQL updates run in a Java Connection (from transaction start to commit)?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, transactions, connection

How can I find all the SQL update queries run in a Java Connection (from transaction start to commit)?

Comment: Please make your question more specific so that others can understand the problem and show your code work you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a normal `Connection`.

You could create wrapper classes for the actual `Connection`/`Statement` classes, that would track which statements have been executed. A better idea would be to just enable logging of SQL if your driver supports it, otherwise you're just recreating an existing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Some other options (on database level):

- Enable and configure AUDITING; or
- Enable SQL tracing of the relevant database session(s)